# claim-construction & claims-construction tags should be combined into 1 tag with the other being a synonym/alias

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms, exact-duplicates

The [claim-constuction] (singular) tag currently has 54 questions whereas the [claims-constuction] (plural) tag currently has 19 questions, not properly subtracting out any questions that have tagged both.  This bifurcation is needless, confusing, and unfortunate, as there is no substantial difference between questions for drafting a single claim versus multiple claims.  One tag (e.g., claim-construction) should be the sole tag for this topic, whereas the other one (e.g., claims-construction) should be demoted to a synonym/alias of the other one.

Indeed, I will be submitting edits to convert over all of the questions tagged [claims-construction] to instead be [claim-construction].  Conversely, I have insufficient reputation to enact the demotion of [claims-construction] to be a synonym/alias of [claim-construction].

Answer (score 1):

Agreed. I'll see what I can do about eliminating the [claims-construction] tag. Although I'm a moderator, I'm a inexperienced one.

Edit:

I believe that I've merged the tags and retained the [claim-construction] tag. This is the first time I've tried this so I could have made an error.